# Nested transaction.atomic() context manager avoid rollback when outer transaction fail

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, transactions, django-orm

I've following scenario:

```
@transaction.atomic()
def some_method():
    # some database logic
    a.save()  # Success. Eligible for Rollback.

    with transaction.atomic():
        # some more database logic
        # Success. Shouldn't be rollbacked
        b.save()

    raise Exception
```

What I want to do is, when I raise Exception, the changes of inner transaction bloc shouldn't be rollbacked, but the one done in outer block should be.

That means, rollback - `a.save()`, but commit `b.save()`. Is that possible? I guess the context manager there creates a save point. So, if the inner block runs successfully, shouldn't it commit till the save point? How exactly will it behave in this scenario?

I read the [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic), which says that:

> atomic blocks can be nested. In this case, when an inner block
>   completes successfully, its effects **can** still be rolled back if an
>   exception is raised in the outer block at a later point.

It says, it can be rolled back, but not it **will** be rollbacked. What exactly does it mean? Is rollback certain?

Comment: By the very definition of a transaction, you cannot commit `b.save()` if the transaction itself fails. You need to rethink the structure of your transaction/savepoint blocks.

Comment: It **will** be rolled back if there is an exception anywhere in the containing transaction. Read it like this: "When an inner block completes successfully, its effects can still be rolled back. Specifically, if an exception is raised in the outer block at a later point, the whole transaction will be rolled back, including the inner block."

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you added `@transaction.atomic` to `some_method` if an `Exception` occurs anywhere inside, everything will be rolled back.

Now, if you remove the decorator and raise the `Exception` inside the atomic block you more or less get what you wanted : b will be commited, a not.

```
def some_method(request):
    b.save()

    with transaction.atomic():
        a.save()
        raise Exception('')
```

In this case, if you raise the `Exception` outside the block, everything (before the `Exception`) will be commited (no `Exception` raised inside a transaction)

I believe that the documentation excerpt refers to the following case :

```
def funA():
    with transaction.atomic():
        funB()
        #code A

def funB():
    with transaction.atomic():
        #code B
```

If an `Exception` occurs in *code A*, everything in *code B* will be rolled back.